# NHibernate conditional computed field (Hibernate can help too)

Tags: nhibernate, computed-field

I need to create computed fields in NHibernate, but in these fields I must use conditional expressions. MySQL example:

```sql
if(now() < addtime(?1, ?2), 'true', 'false')
```

The computed field is stored in the database, and when the program needs this field, the program gets it from database, uses it to create a projection and finally, NHibernate proceeds with the execution of the full query.

How do I create any computed field containing functions with NHibernate instead of creating the field manually for each dialect (Microsoft SQL, Postgresql or MySQL)?

Comment: Do you really need the computed field on database? You could create a property on your class and calculate it using C#.

Comment: Sure, I need to do that. Because, the model works fine but only when the database based on MySQL dialect. Moreover, when I update manually the field in database for M$ SQL `'if (getdate() < dateadd(s, ?2, ?1), ''true'', ''false'')'`, the query that use the computed field works too. So I want just NHibernate create the field and next store it in the database.